# StreamingDataflowWorker$KeyCommitTooLargeException. Commit request for stage S8 and key 8 is larger than 2GB in gcp Dataflow

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Got the below error in one of the pipeline
**org.apache.beam.runners.dataflow.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$KeyCommitTooLargeException: Commit request for stage S2 and key 8f7ac37b-b73b-4d6f-9ac5-c709ee5946d4 is larger than 2GB and cannot be processed. This may be caused by grouping a very large amount of data in a single window without using Combine, or by producing a large amount of data from a single input element.**

***Here is the snippet of the code:***

```
 private static String extractViewName(SyncDto json) {
    if (json.getViewName() != null) {
        return json.getViewName();
    } else if (isNotEmpty(json.getNetworkAvailabilityResponse())) {
        return json.getNetworkAvailabilityResponse().get(0).getViewName();
    } else if (isNotEmpty(json.getLocationAvailabilityResponse())) {
        return json.getLocationAvailabilityResponse().get(0).getViewName();
    }
    return null;
}
private static String getViewOrganisation(SyncDto json) {
    String viewName = extractViewName(json);
    if (viewName != null) {
        String[] splits = viewName.split(" ");
        return splits.length > 0 ? splits[0] : null;
    }
    return null;
}

private static MapElements<TryDto<SyncDto>, KV<String, TryDto<SyncDto>>> extractView() {
    return MapElements
        .into(new TypeDescriptor<KV<String, TryDto<SyncDto>>>() {
        })
        .via(tryDto -> {
            if (tryDto.isSuccess()) {
                SyncDto dto = tryDto.getTry().get();
                if (dto.getTransactionNumber() != null) {
                    return KV.of(dto.getTransactionNumber(), tryDto);
                }else {
                    log.error("TransactionNumber is null");
                }
            }
            return KV.of("unknown", tryDto);
        });
}

private PCollection<Iterable<TryDto<SyncDto>>> getViewPCollection(TupleTag<TryDto<SyncDto>> tag,
                                                                   PCollectionTuple batchesByView,long sessionMinutesDuration) {
    return batchesByView.get(tag)
        .apply("Extract " + tag.getId() + " by viewId", extractView())
        .apply("Accumulating " + tag.getId(), SyncSessionWindow.get(sessionMinutesDuration))
        .apply("Group " + tag.getId() + " by view id", GroupByKey.create())
        .apply("Extract " + tag.getId() + " Iterable value", Values.create());
}

private void tmwBopisFlow(PCollection<Iterable<TryDto<SyncDto>>> tmwBopisMessages, Integer skuFailedSyncThreshold) {
    LocationMessagesSyncCountSplitter countSplitter
        = new LocationMessagesSyncCountSplitter(TMW_BOPIS, skuFailedSyncThreshold);

    PCollectionTuple tmwBopisCounted = tmwBopisMessages.apply("Count TMW BOPIS", ParDo.of(countSplitter)
        .withOutputTags(countSplitter.getSuccessTag(), TupleTagList.of(countSplitter.getFailureTag())));

    tmwBopisCounted.get(countSplitter.getSuccessTag())
        .setCoder(TryDtoCoder.of(SerializableCoder.of(SyncDto.class)))
        .apply("Convert to model TMW BOPIS", ParDo.of(new LocationModelConverter()))
        .apply("Write to TMW BOPIS", tmwBopisSink);
```

[[image: The below is the screenshot of pipeline]]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6Bez.png)

Comment: It's not clear where getViewPCollection is being used. What does your Count TMW BOPIS step do?

Comment: @robertwb tmw bopis is the final pcollection before writing into db. In Count TMW BOPIS step we accumulate all the Values of a key in single PCollection and once all the records are inserted to db, one done record will be created in the end.

Comment: There still doesn't seem to be enough context in the code above to be sure what the problem is (a minimal reproduction of the issue would be quite helpful) but if you're trying to write all the values at the same time that could be an issue and perhaps you could split it up into several writes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is a case of "*grouping a very large amount of data in a single window without using Combine*." In your

```
        .apply("Extract " + tag.getId() + " Iterable value", Values.create());
```

step you may have more than 2GB of values for a given key. Rather than materialize this (large) set of values, you should process them by iterating over the iterable in a DoFn. Even better if you can do a [Combine](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#combine).

Comment: Hi Rober, we are actually iterating the whole inbound in groupby stage itself. is there any transformer for compressing data before writing to next stage?